# Flash & Javascript - __flash__removeCallback

Tags: javascript, flash, joomla

I put object and embed tag in a why page and run on IE

Everything is ok.

But when i put object & embed tag in a page of joomla

I get immediately error ( i think joomla have problem )

```
__flash__removeCallback(document.getElementById("flash"), "loadData");

Object doesn't support this property or method
```

it seem like not exists function _*flash*_removeCallBack

I have researched and found documents about problem

http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleFixingFlashExternalInterface

I try to override that function but not effective. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: [Try Sourcer or Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content)

Idea 2: Check filtered content settings [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085746/joomla-how-to-call-filter-text/8230053#8230053)