# joomla how to call filter text

Tags: joomla, filter, joomla1.7

I am developing a Joomla plugin and I would like to call the filter text settings

To illustrate exactly what I am trying to access:

From back end > article manager > options > filter text tab > here we set the filtering text for the editors. The settings are assign to group of users, and these can be White List, Black list, No html, No filter...

I am looking for something like `jSomething::something`

Anybody?

Thank you

RESPONDING TO POSTING IMAGE

[image: Article Manager Options Icon]

[image: Article Manager Options Icon]

Comment: could u post a screenshot , i couldn't `find back end > article manager > options > filter text tab`

Comment: @Synxmax I have added snap shots of how to find the settings I want access through the classes of the joomla framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for JFilterInput

[API Reference](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/Filter/JFilterInput.html)

Usage is actually:

```
clean($source, $type='string')
```

[Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/API15%3aJFilterInput/clean)

Comment: I would like to access the configuration, not to clean the code. I want to check for text filter configured for a group of users. Example, author such and such publishes certain html content; check: is the user allowed to published this html (jsomething::something is called and I get a list of groups and their allowed html, if any) Checking you response, if you have any further comments please post. Thank you

Comment: Check out the filterText function (line 88) in 'Joomlaroot/administrator/components/com_content/helpers/content.php' for checking user groups against filtering